# 2sxc Custom Color-Picker Input Field not working

Tags: 2sxc

I'm trying to use the 2sxc Custom Color-Picker Input Field using the tutorial on: https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/ui211/page.

The issue is the color picker is not showing and also the demo on the page of the tutorial is also not working. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a timing issue - we should look at this ASAP, thx. I just created an issue here: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2526

is fixed in 12.05, to be released this week.